# removing lines with special characters in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this:

```
VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN 2888
ACP*VRWPIYTACGP 292
RDRKSTRLNSSHVVTSRMP 114
VAREA*KAVVLRDRRAHV*T    73
```

in the 1st column in some rows there is a "`*`". I want to remove all the lines with that '`*`'. here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN 2888
RDRKSTRLNSSHVVTSRMP 114
```

to do so, I am using this code:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ if(($1 == '*')) { print $1 "," $2} }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

this code does not return the expected output. how can I fix it?

Comment: Regarding `$1 == '*'` - you can't use `'` in a `'`-delimited script. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670702/133219.

Answer (score 3):

*how can I fix it?*

You did

```
awk -F "\t" '{ if(($1 == '*')) { print $1 "," $2} }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

by doing `$1 == "*"` you are asking: is first field `*` *not* does first contain `*`? You might use [index](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function which does return position of match if found or 0 otherwise. Let `infile.txt` content be

```
VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN 2888
ACP*VRWPIYTACGP 292
RDRKSTRLNSSHVVTSRMP 114
VAREA*KAVVLRDRRAHV*T    73
```

then

```
awk 'index($1,"*")==0{print $1,$2}' infile.txt
```

output

```
VAREAKAVVLRDRKSTRLN 2888
RDRKSTRLNSSHVVTSRMP 114
```

Note that if you use `index` rather than pattern `/`...`/` you do not have to care about characters with special meaning, e.g. `.`. Note that for data you have you do not have to set field separator (`FS`) explicitly. **Important** `'` is not legal string delimiter in GNU `AWK`, you should use `"` for that purpose, unless your intent is to summon hard to find bugs.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: `'index($1,"*")==0{print $1,$2}'` = `'!index($1,"*")'`.

Comment: Nothing in your script is gawk-only btw, it'll behave the same way in any awk.

Comment: @EdMorton I repaired my answer, I did not know that GNU `AWK` has gimmick for comparing field against list of files under the directory I'm executing this command from.

Comment: actually I was wrong with that comment but what I had in mind was nothing to do with awk. The `*` within the `'`s is exposed to the shell so I thought the shell would expand that to the files in the current dir but I just tried it and that didn't happen (and I'm too lazy to think about why!).

Comment: Ah, I know why - because the shell is including the rest of the awk script in the globbing pattern, just like if you wrote `ls 'foo'*'bar'` rather  than `ls 'foo' * 'bar'`.

Comment: Now I confused, but I hope we might agree `"` should be used for delimiting strings, not `'` which might lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: `"` should be used. Sorry if I confused you, I was trying to explain WHY `"` should be used and what happens if you use `'` instead, I just gave a bad example of the result. I explain the issue in detail at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670702/133219.

Answer (score 2):

with your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '$1!~/\*/' Input_file
```

***OR*** above will print complete line when condition is NOT matched, in case you want to print only 1st and 2nd fields of matched condition line then try following:

```
awk '$1!~/\*/{print $1,$2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` like so to remove the lines that contain literal asterisk (`*`). Note that it should be escaped with a backslash (`\*`) or put in a character class (`[*]`) to prevent `grep` from interpreting `*` as a modifier meaning 0 or more characters:

```
echo "A*B\nCD" | grep -v '[*]'
CD
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-v` : Print lines that do **not** match.